# how are the coordinates of the islands established?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have the following code that solves this problem:

"Given a non-empty 2D array grid of 0's and 1's, an island is a group of 1's (representing land) connected 4-directionally (horizontal or vertical.) You may assume all four edges of the grid are surrounded by water.

Count the number of distinct islands. An island is considered to be the same as another if and only if one island can be translated (and not rotated or reflected) to equal the other."
Link to question:https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-distinct-islands/

```
        # Do a DFS to find all cells in the current island.
        def dfs(row, col):
            if row < 0 or col < 0 or row >= len(grid) or col >= len(grid[0]):
                return
            if (row, col) in seen or not grid[row][col]:
                return
            seen.add((row, col))
            current_island.append((row - row_origin, col - col_origin))
            dfs(row + 1, col)
            dfs(row - 1, col)
            dfs(row, col + 1)
            dfs(row, col - 1)
```

The code above is part of the solution to the question.

My question is on the line 'current-island.append'; what does this line and the rest of the code do?

Note I get that for example dfs(row +1,col) runs the dfs function with row+1,col as the input.
But how are we appending current_island without initiating it? I am assuming current_island is something like [0,0,0,0] to begin with, then we append (or add 1) to each index to represent the islands?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of script from .append onwards:

`.append` just adds a value to the end of a python list.

Then the lines underneath just call an earlier definition of the `dfs()` function.

Comment: Hi Sergei, I understood both of those things and I pointed out explicitly that I understand that. What I don't see is how the DFS helps us to identify all of the 'islands'

Comment: Or rather, what does 'row' and 'col' represent?